# Why are some solutions to ODE with complex eigenvalues ignored?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was given $\ddot x+6\dot x+13 x=0$. Of course I wrote: $\dot x = y, \dot y=-6y-13 x$ which gives $p(\lambda)=(\lambda)(\lambda+6)+13$ which gives: $\lambda=-3\pm 2i$. Answers give this solution: $x=c_1 e^{-3t}\cos(2t)+e^{-3t}\cos(2t)$, which seems to be related to the first eigenvalue, but:

1. Where is the "i"? (I guess it is already included in $c_2$)
2. What about the second eigenvalue?
3. Shouldn't the second term be multiplied by $t$ as follows from solving this kind of equations? I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct general solution is 
$$x=c_1 e^{-3t}\cos(2t)+c_2 e^{-3t}\sin (2t),\quad c_1,c_2\in\mathbb{R}\tag{1}$$

*Explanation*. Even when the eigenvalues are complex, we want *real solutions*. So, writing 
$$x=A_1 e^{(-3+2i) t} +A_2 e^{(-3-2i)t},\quad A_1,A_2\in\mathbb{C} \tag{2}$$
would not be the form we want, although this is the general solution over complex numbers. Starting from (2), one uses the Euler formula
$e^{2it} = \cos 2t + i \sin 2t$, splits coefficients into real-imaginary parts, multiplies everything out, and discards imaginary terms. The result is (1).

The second eigenvalue was not ignored. One needs both $e^{2it}$ and $e^{-2it}$ to build $\cos 2t$ and $\sin 2t$.

Comment: Put another way, the constraint that the solution is real puts a constraint on $A_1,A_2$ which winds up with the form in (1).

Comment: What's the justification for dropping the imaginary unit from $isin(2t)$?

Comment: @BradVelasquez It's a linear equation, we can divide by any constant.  If $i\sin 2t$ is a solution, then $\sin 2t$ is also a solution.